# Do not write logs to the database NLog + ASP .NET 5 + SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

My application is built on ASP .NET 5
I used to do a project on .NET Core and everything was OK, there were no problems with logs. But in ASP.NET 5 I do not understand how to do this
I'm trying to write logs to the database using this config:

https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target#example-configurations

This is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <!-- optional, add some variables
  https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables
  -->
  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>

  <!--
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>
  <target name="database" xsi:type="Database">

    <connectionStringName>"Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=LocalDB;User ID=sa;Password=1234;"</connectionStringName>


    <commandText>
      insert into dbo.LogExcelWorker (
      Application, Logged, Level, Message,
      Username,
      ServerName, Port, Url, Https,
      ServerAddress, RemoteAddress,
      Logger, CallSite, Exception
      ) values (
      @Application, @Logged, @Level, @Message,
      @Username,
      @ServerName, @Port, @Url, @Https,
      @ServerAddress, @RemoteAddress,
      @Logger, @Callsite, @Exception
      );
    </commandText>

    <parameter name="@application" layout="${appsetting:name=AppName:default=Unknown\: set AppName in appSettings}" />
    <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
    <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
    <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />

    <parameter name="@username" layout="${identity}" />

    <parameter name="@serverName" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME}" />
    <parameter name="@port" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_PORT}" />
    <parameter name="@url" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_URL}" />
    <parameter name="@https" layout="${when:inner=1:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' == 'on'}${when:inner=0:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' != 'on'}" />

    <parameter name="@serverAddress" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=LOCAL_ADDR}" />
    <parameter name="@remoteAddress" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_ADDR}:${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_PORT}" />

    <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
    <parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite}" />
    <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
  </target>
</targets>
  <rules>

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="database" /> 
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I created the table in the database

I try to make a test call of logs but nothing is written down:

```
    public string Index()
    {
        Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        log.Trace( "trace message" );
        log.Debug( "debug message" );
        log.Info( "info message" );
        log.Warn( "warn message" );
        log.Error( "error message" );
        log.Fatal( "fatal message" );

        return "start...";
    }
```

But there are no records in the database

Comment: `connectionStringName` doesn't look correct. It should just be `connectionString` with no quotes around its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WriteTog property is wrong**

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="f" />
```

should be in your case

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="database" />
```

(Change name of target)

General in cases like this enable internal log. This will help you a lot. Here a sample how to enable:

```
internalLogLevel="trace" 
internalLogFile="log/internal-nlog.txt"
throwExceptions="true"  
throwConfigExceptions="true"
```

Comment: Did as you said, but without result. Maybe I'm doing something else wrong?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov: Add the following in your nlog config.  internalLogLevel="trace" internalLogFile="log/internal-nlog.txt" throwExceptions="true" throwConfigExceptions="true" so you should see error inside log/internal-nlog.txt

Comment: Your advice has helped. Before the database, I got through. But now I have such an error Converting the nvarchar data type to a datetime data type has resulted in a value out of range.
The execution of this instruction has been interrupted.
I think the problem is in the parameter:

2018-03-19 16: 40: 15.2021 Trace Parameter: '@logged' = '2018/03/19 16: 40: 14.791' (String)

Comment: I solved the problem like this: <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fff}" />

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to the correct target-name

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="database" />
```

Comment: Did as you said, but without result. Maybe I'm doing something else wrong?